# Virtualbox freezes entire Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

From yesterday I can't boot the Windows 7 through virtualbox running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. The entire computer would be frozen right after I double click the Windows 7 icon. I had to manually force reboot the computer every time I boot the virtualbox (ctrl+alt+F1/* doesn't help). I have tried:

a) remove and reinstall virtualbox;

b) delete Windows 7 but can't reinstall the windows due to computer freezing.

Here are some session information:

```
$lsb_release
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04

$vboxmanage --version
5.0.40_Ubuntur115130

$ sudo VBoxManage list extpacks
Extension Packs: 1
Pack no. 0:   VNC
Version:      5.0.40
Revision:     115130
Edition:      
Description:  VNC plugin module
VRDE Module:  VBoxVNC
Usable:       true 
Why unusable:
```

Any suggestions for the solution?

Comment: Maybe you are running out of RAM

Comment: Should be not because it was running without any issue before yesterday and memory size was 8G (and flexible with the entire PC's 64G memory).

Comment: As least it should be able to reinstall the windows if it was due to RAM.

Comment: Are all cores at 100% when using the VB?

Comment: Unable to check due to freezing actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by deleting the current version and installed an older virtualbox version (5.2.2 r119230). Probably some bugs in current release for Ubuntu 16.04.